# internet explorer 7&8 print layout problems

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, devil

I have created a print button on my site which launches the print dialogue box. I also have a print.css file which is used to layout the print document. In this print.css file I have discarded everything I don't need. Only the logo of the company, title of the page, the header image and the relevant content will print.

All looks dandy when I view it with the web developer toolbar in FF. When testing in Internet Explorer I get random text and my logo image decides it is going to sit anywhere it likes.

Is there a resource of best print practices to follow for printing, specifically in IE?

Comment: Ok, after some reading I have managed to find some answers. One of them being by Eric Meyer talking about floats. So I have nulled everything in my print.css using *{margin:0;padding:0;floats:none;} and that seems to have sorted out the layout issues in IE8. Next question...

Comment: The print dialogue box take FOREVER to fire up when I click on the print button. Does anyone know what might cause this behavior?

Comment: probably networked printers. Do you have many of those?

Comment: Hi Frédéric. Yes, it's a networked printer and we only have one in the office. All other browsers open the dialog box instantly but IE, all versions, takes a long time top open it. Thanks